# Can't chgrp in NFS4 mounts

Tags: linux, nfs, kerberos

I'm using Linux in a large multi-user network. Let *A* be some group which I'm am member of, but which is not my primary group. According to `chmod(2)` I should be able to `chgrp` a file to group *A*. Trying to do so succeeds on a local as well as on a NFSv3 mount, but not on a NFSv4/Kerberos mount (`EPERM`). Are there any special considerations regarding `chgrp` when using NFSv4 mounts?

Answer (score 3):

This probably has to do with the fact you are using no_root_squash (root= in /etc/dfs/dfstab) specified as the nfs client.

You are passing named user/group NFSv4 while in NFSv3 this was ID based.

So your options are to either specify NFSv3 or to ensure that the users/groups exist on both the cilent and server keeping their id's matched up.

If the names and groups are out of sync with the server/client you can have some wacky chown/chgrp issues.

Comment: Thank you, I was having the same problem as Philipp. It's good to know that NFSv4 sends only the name of user or group and therefore I cannot "chgrp" to a group that the server does not have a record of. Unfortunately I don't have a central directory available (NIS or LDAP), so I might end up using NFSv3.